# User selectable sort in for-loop list with Jinja2, HTML, and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, jinja2

I have a list made using for-loop in jija2 in HTML.  I want to have a "sort" button where a user can click to sort, toggling ascending/descending order.  Similar question to this problem found in stackoverflow:
[Sort list of objects with Jinja2 and Flask depending the field pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990914/sort-list-of-objects-with-jinja2-and-flask-depending-the-field-pressed)
The answer contained how I should setup, but I still am struggling how to implement.

I have the list setup as:

```
 <!-- This is for "default" -->
    {% set sort_on = 'lastName' %}
    {% set order_rev = True %}

<!-- This is the "sort" function I want to call -->
<input type="button" value="Sort by Name" style='display:inline' onclick="sorter();"/>

<!-- Below is the list -->
{% for profile in profileList|sort(attribute=sort_on, reverse=order_rev) %}
<div class="row" id="table">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="name">
        <strong>{{profile["lastName"]}}, {{profile["firstName"]}}</strong>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-1" id="score">
            {{profile["score"]}}    
        </div>
</div>
```

And I want to toggle the below in a javascript (or any other suggestion?):

```
<script>
function Sorter(){
if(toggler==1){
    {% set sort_on = 'lastName' %}
    {% set order_rev = True %}
    toggler = 0
}else{
    {% set sort_on = 'lastName' %}
    {% set order_rev = False %}
    toggler = 1
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried above code, but I do not know how to call the function and perform the sort without refreshing the page, and once refreshed, no settings are saved so goes back to default.

If you have a better solution (and not what I explained above), please suggest!

Please advise.  Your input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are confusing server-side with client side code here; Jinja is run entirely server-side, you cannot alter what is rendered by setting JS on the client side.

Comment: Can you please provide a guidance as to how I should implement the sort function?  Thank you @MartijnPieters for your input.

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on SO showing how to handle client-side sorting too. The post you linked to handles server-side sorting. And then there is an option to use AJAX to load a new version of just the table, sorted server side. But giving you an example of all those would be too broad.

Comment: I was able to use List.js and now all the <div> that I care about are functioning as client-side sorting, working very nicely.  Thank you for pointing me to the right direction @MartijnPieters